# How to get input tag and option tag separately and load inside div and inside select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have empty `<div>` and `<select>`  want to load label and input tags inside div and `option` inside **select** after ajax response. How would i do that?

here is the response 
[image]

i want to separately extract label and input for `<div>` & extract option for `<select>`.
here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<select id="student" name="student" class="form-control" onchange="getName(this.value)">

</select>
</div>
<div name="state" id="state">



</div> 

<script>
function getschool() {
var st = $('#school option:selected').val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>Choice/student',
    type: 'POST',
        data: {
            // fname: fname
            st:st



        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            //alert(data[0].id);
            // for(k in data){
                // alert(data[k].id);
                $('#student').html(data);
               //$('#state').html(data.input);
                $('#state').html(data);
            // }
            //$('body').html(data);
            // console.log(data);
            //alert(data);
            //alert("Succesful ");
            //location.reload(false);
            //window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/choicelaunch/Choice/order_fullmenu";
        }

});
}

</script>
```

After doing so i get every thing inside div like:[image]

Plus i am getting this reponse from my Codeigniter controller:

```
public function student()
    {
        $sch= $this->input->post('st');
        $swt=$this->data['school'] = $this->catering_model->selstu($sch);

        //echo(json_encode( $swt));
        if(!empty($swt))
        {
            if(($sch == "1"))
            {
                echo ('<label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="offer1" name="offer" value="Monday">Monday
                </label>');

            }
            foreach($swt as $in)
            {

                echo ('<option value="'.$in->id.'" select="select">'.$in->fname.'&nbsp;'.'</option>');


            }

        }


        //var_dump($data['school']);
    }
```

i dnt knw why. i only need checkbox not non-checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `filter()`:

```
$('#student').html($(data).filter('option'));
$('#state').html($(data).filter('label'));
```

Comment: says Object object

Comment: @user3162878 Oh, sorry,`find` won't work, please try with `filter`; see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's little bit tricky. But, try this one.

Why don't you try to add a separator between div content and select content on controller. Here what I mean:

```
    public function student()
    {
        $sch= $this->input->post('st');
        $swt=$this->data['school'] = $this->catering_model->selstu($sch);

        //echo(json_encode( $swt));
        if(!empty($swt))
        {
            if(($sch == "1"))
            {
                echo ('<label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" id="offer1" name="offer" value="Monday">Monday
                </label>');

            }
            echo "@@"; //the separator
            foreach($swt as $in)
            {

                echo ('<option value="'.$in->id.'" select="select">'.$in->fname.'&nbsp;'.'</option>');


            }
```

Then, after success receive data, try to split it.

```
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        var res = data.split("@@");
        $('#student').html(res[0]);
        $('#state').html(res[1]);
    }
```